# Nmap Joomla Brute-Forcing functioning incorrectly

Tags: apache, http, joomla, nmap

I am performing password auditing of a Joomla site using Nmap and it seems to be functioning incorrectly. I am using the Nmap Joomla brute-force script with a password list from John the Ripper that contains the password of the site administrator.

```
nmap -Pn -n -p 80 --script http-joomla-brute \
--script-args 'userdb="joomla-users.txt",passdb="/usr/share/john/password.lst",\
http-joomla-brute.threads=5,unpwdb.timelimit=0,\
brute.firstonly=true' X.X.X.X
```

For some reason, it only attempts 5 guesses and then stops. None of the credentials provided are correct. This is the output that I keep getting:

```
Starting Nmap 6.47 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2014-10-25 07:23 EDT
Nmap scan report for 172.16.1.3
Host is up (0.19s latency).
PORT   STATE SERVICE
80/tcp open  http
| http-joomla-brute: 
|   Accounts
|     admin:12345 - Valid credentials
|     admin:123456 - Valid credentials
|     admin:admin
|     admin:admin - Valid credentials
|     admin:password - Valid credentials
|     admin:password1 - Valid credentials
|   Statistics
|_    Performed 5 guesses in 1 seconds, average tps: 5
```

I tried using http-formb-brute instead and it does try all of the passwords in the password file, however it is unable to confirm which one is the valid credential used to login.

```
nmap -Pn -n -p 80 --script http-form-brute \ 
--script-args 'http-form-brute.path="/administrator/index.php",\
http-form-brute.uservar="username",http-form-brute.passvar="passwd",\
userdb="./joomla-users.txt",passdb="/usr/share/john/password.lst",\
brute.firstonly=true,brute.threads=5' X.X.X.X
```

Comment: And why may I ask are you trying to brute force?

Comment: Because he is performing a password auditing of a Joomla site ? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_technology_security_audit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your question is "Why is this not working ? How can it be fixed ?" if I understand well.

Most nmap scripts are written in Lua, and a few in C I believe. You can find more about Nmap Scripting Engine on http://nmap.org/book/nse.html. The script seems to stop looking for credentials after finding 5 successful auth.

In order to understand why you get those false positive, I believe you have to take notes of the **version of the script** (http-joomla-brute), analyse its **source code** (https://svn.nmap.org/nmap/scripts/http-joomla-brute.nse), and get a **network capture (pcap)** **from the client** (from where you run nmap) and **from the server** (that you're trying to brute-force : assuming it is yours).

The script seems to interpret whatever HTTP answer as a successful authentication. this may be a joomla update for obvious security reason, or the script may be defunct/obsolete.
Either way, analyzing what the script is interpreting against what you read in the HTTP frames (TCP packets) would give you the answer you are looking for.

Note: The script author may be able to help. (Author: Paulino Calderon - calderon@websec.mx)